# F# applying function to two lists at once

Tags: list, f#, functional-programming

I'm just jumping into F# on my own, doing a translation of a simple financial tool as an exercise. And I'm still waiting for reference books in the mail. Here's something I imagine F# can do in probably more than one clever clever way, but I can't get past syntax errors.

I have a function called Delta for options valuation, and I want to apply it--over two (parallel) lists of input values:

```
let Delta f k v t r = exp(-r * t) * CDF(D1 f k v t)

let priceList = [100.0; 98.0; 102.0; 100.0]  //f
let strike = 100.0                           //k
let vol = 0.30                               //v
let timeList = [1.0; 0.9; 0.8; 0.7]          //t
let rt = 0.005                               //r
```

So this function is part of a recursive process (using Newton's Method). I would be happy producing a list of deltas of the same length [d1; d2; d3; d4] [edited: I'm sticking to the list of deltas as desired result]. I'm looking for the clever F# way--in one fell swoop--with list functions. I've tried to shoehorn this Delta function into this basic pattern:

```
  let sumList = List.map2 (fun x y -> x + y) list1 list2
```

(It seems like many of the list functions could get me a Delta list or a sum of Delta list.) I'm not coming close to guessing legal syntax. I've also tried the "Match head :: tail" pattern too.

EDIT: I waffled here on what I am asking for because I'm swimming a bit in all the List. functions that are new to me. Let me focus myself: Can I apply (Delta f k v t r) as (Delta priceList strike vol timeList rt) and produce deltaList, with prices, times and deltas all being the same length?

Comment: I'm not sure I got that right, do you want to run apply function memberwise to both lists..? If that's the case (and lists are of equal length), you could zip them both together and map the result over the resulting zipped list.

Comment: if they are not the same length you can just use `Seq.zip` - this will stop as soon as one list runs try (but it will give you a `seq` back)

Comment: @Carsten It is fairly easy to write a version of `Seq.zip` that fills in the shorter input sequence with a specified default value.

Comment: I should have been more focused in the first place: but I'll stick to asking for the list of deltas (delta function results) that is the same length as the lists of prices and times. So trying to apply function to two lists at once and return a list. Let me experiment with Zip a bit now. Thanks.

Comment: If I go to the zip function and turn the two lists into one list of 2-tuples, does that require changing the function signature of arguments? Or is there more list function cleverness to use the tuples list?

Comment: I'm unsure i have understood even half of the subject but if the question is just "_Can I apply (Delta f k v t r) as (Delta priceList strike vol timeList rt) and produce deltaList, with prices, times and deltas all being the same length?_" then shouldn't that be enough ? `let Delta f k v t r = List.map2 (fun f t -> expr(-r * t) * CDF(D1, f k v t)) f t`

Comment: Could you please add some sample input and corresponding expected output, so that it may become clear what you want to do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As others pointed out in the comment, your question is not entirely clear - if you gave a concrete example of input and output you want to get, it would be easier to answer.

That said, if you want to call `Delta` with the various values as parameters, then there are two things you need to do. Most parameters are just plain values, so those you can pass directly; `priceList` and `timeList` are collections, so I assume you want to calculate `Delta` for all its elements. To do that, you can use `Seq.zip` and `Seq.map`:

```
Seq.zip priceList timeList 
|> Seq.map (fun (f, t) -> Delta f strike vol t rt)
```

Comment: Thanks much. Sorry I didn't try to explicate more, but I felt like I was starting to talk my way into even more of a morass so I hesitated. This is perfect. Hopefully I start to get an intuitive feel for this efficient but somewhat cryptic syntax. Thanks again.

Comment: One other observation I'd make as a newbie is that as I have scoured online tutorials, I don't really see Seq. function examples. Just mostly List. functions. Another totally separate solution with Seq. I eventually found was Seq.skip ... |> Seq.take ... |> Seq.toList for sub-lists. Hopefully I get a good reference in book form.

Comment: @RomnieEE Self promotion alert: My Pluralsight course "F# Functional Data Structures" covers Seqs (and other collections) in some, hopefully useful, detail.